# How to embed JasperReports Viewer in web application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The following code launch the report in *JasperViewer* generated by `jrxml`

```
net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer jv = 
    new net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer(jasperPrint);  
jv.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
```

How can i embed the same viewer  into my web application, so that user can able to use the same,
it can be a applet or else any one knows other way work around?

Comment: Duplicate of [View report using JasperViewer or something else in web application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16957825/876298) post