# Integrate JasperReports Viewer Like Component inside an AngularJs Component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasper-reports, polymer, web-component

I have been researching this problem for some time and have seen few references (like [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817209/embed-reportviewer-website-using-angularjs)).

[I know the Viewer is a Swing component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957825/view-report-using-jasperviewer-or-something-else-in-web-application), but I would like to achieve something like integrating/having a container in which to preview reports.

I have not seen any such component default provided by Angular. Has anyone attempted something similar or is it better to create own web components (Polymer-wise perhaps).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is not really possible, due to reasons above.

Just now saw a related idea/approach: just exporting a report as html and providing to an html rendering container, like angular's ng-bind-html (something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)).

For now, just another "two cents" in, though.

Comment: Whatever you do you'll have to implement a decent amount of logic in your own javascript it seems. I'd recommend Polymer over Angular personally just based on the learning curve but both are good choices.

Comment: Yes, I would also favour Polymer concept-wise, at least. But my projects requirements are "directing" me to Angular. It's gonna be a bit of a learning process, but I look forward to the fun part of it :).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say about viewer but yeah it's possibility of visualize.js for your requirement.
With Visualize.js, anyone building a Web application can more easily include powerful analytics as an integrated experience. Developers can embed highly interactive visualizations and reports with more control and power than previously available using iFrames, charting libraries, or using other BI vendor solutions. Visualize.js leverages the REST APIs of the Jaspersoft analytic server for built-in services such as data connectivity, repository access, in-memory analytics, and visualization design.  Visualize.js offers on-premises or cloud deployment options and low-cost subscription or utility pricing.