# Can we use JasperReports with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasper-reports, reporting

I have been looking for a reporting tool for *AngularJS* and have been without luck.

I wanted to know if we can use JasperReports with AngularJS. I stumbled upon [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817209/embed-reportviewer-website-using-angularjs) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744758/integrate-jasperreports-viewer-like-component-inside-an-angularjs-component). But they didn't help much.

Any help would be great!

PS: In case *JasperReports* cannot be used with *AngularJS*, are there any reporting platforms for AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, long answer: No, Jasper Reports is based on Java, so you'll need to setup a Java server (or a Jasper Reports Server) that renders to HTML and then use that HTML output in an Iframe or inlined in your code using some server side technology, speaking of which, depeding of your server side technology you may also find a Jasper Reports implementation for your particular server side technology.

Comment: We have node js communicating with MongoDB at the server side, I found that Jasper can talk to MongoDB. Let's see if we can connect node to Jasper somehow.

Comment: I m seeing this topic, I also have to use Jasper Report with angularjs and Java /Mysql on server side, did you manage to do it?

Comment: No we shifted to another reporting platform at jsreport.net Jasper is very powerful but somehow we had too different needs and getting it done via Jasper had become painfully time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look for Visualize.js. Maybe it would be useful for your case.